# AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django

Has anyone an idea why I got this error? That the attribute `all` is not on the object

```
Subject.course_set.all()
```

If I do this for testing, it works.

```
Course.objects.all()[0].subjects.all()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Subject.course_set.all()` makes no sense. You have to call it on model's instance instead of a class, eg:

```
subject = Subject.objects.all()[0]
#^ this is an instance
subject.course_set.all()
```